# any way to input dynamic amount of "'secondary_y':True" in the specs of make_subplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

primary question :
i am trying to dynamically generate subplots in plotly-python, using an array of "regions".

is there any way to do something about the following part of code using my array of regions? in the snippet of code i manually put the 4 lines of `{ 'secondary_y':True } ,`)

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1 ,
    cols=len( arr___regions ) ,
    subplot_titles=arr___regions ,
    shared_yaxes=True ,
    specs = [
        [
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            ]
        ]
    )
```

tried a few searches but could not find anything ; not sure if im using the correct search terms.

or maybe there is some fundamentals about python that im missing?

2ndary question : `shared_yaxes=True` shares the primary Y axes but the 2ndary Y axes are still showing on all subplots. does plotly have anything about shared 2ndary-Y-axes?

full code for both questions :

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio # https://plotly.com/python/templates/
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from io import StringIO

data_source = StringIO('''region|period|sales|quantity
Central|2014-01|1,539.91|62
Central|2014-02|1,233.17|69
Central|2014-03|5,827.60|123
Central|2014-04|3,712.34|80
Central|2014-05|4,048.51|121
Central|2014-06|9,646.30|158
East|2014-01|436.17|33
East|2014-02|199.78|15
East|2014-03|5,943.39|140
East|2014-04|3,054.91|120
East|2014-05|7,250.10|135
East|2014-06|10,759.16|160
South|2014-01|9,322.09|125
South|2014-02|2,028.99|28
South|2014-03|32,911.12|172
South|2014-04|12,184.61|157
South|2014-05|5,779.24|69
South|2014-06|4,560.25|65
West|2014-01|2,938.72|64
West|2014-02|1,057.96|47
West|2014-03|11,008.90|150
West|2014-04|9,343.49|179
West|2014-05|6,570.44|141
West|2014-06|9,629.42|138
''')

odf = pd.read_csv( data_source , delimiter='|' , thousands=',' , )   # "original dataframe"

pio.templates.default = 'presentation'

arr___regions = pd.unique( odf['region'] )
arr___regions.sort()



fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1 ,
    cols=len( arr___regions ) ,
    subplot_titles=arr___regions ,
    shared_yaxes=True ,
    specs = [
        [
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            { 'secondary_y':True } ,
            ]
        ]
    )



sdf = {}   # "sub dataframe"

for idx , region in enumerate( arr___regions , start=0 ):
    sdf[region] = odf[ odf['region'] == region ]

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            name='sales',
            x=sdf[region]['period'],
            y=sdf[region]['sales'],
            ) ,
        row=1,col=(idx+1),
        )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            name='quantity',
            x=sdf[region]['period'],
            y=sdf[region]['quantity'],
            mode='lines+markers',
            line=dict( shape='spline', ) ,
            ) ,
        row=1,col=(idx+1),
        secondary_y=True,
        )



fig.update_xaxes( tickangle=270 , type='category' , )

y_11 = --000
y_12 = 40000
y_21 = y_11*0.010
y_22 = y_12*0.010

fig.update_yaxes(
    title_text='sales',
    range = [ y_11,y_12 ] ,
    )

fig.update_yaxes(
    title_text='quantity',
    secondary_y=True,
    range = [ y_21,y_22 ] ,
    )

fig.update_layout(
    legend_orientation='h' ,
    font = dict( color='#000000' , family='tahoma' , size=10 , ) ,
    margin = dict( l=140,r=140,b=140,t=140,pad=12, ) ,
    )

fig.show()
```

Comment: could you clarify what you're looking for in your secondary question?  [this](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-axes-lowlevel-api) may help.

Comment: oh, that could be what im looking for. thank you for your time.

Comment: just to clarify my secondary question : if i specify shared_yaxes=True then only the first subplot will show the *primary* Y_axis, which, yes, is what i wanted, and i wanted something similar for the secondary Y_axis, which i imagined will show only on the last subplot, but the code that i wrote generated the secondary Y axis for all subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your primary question you can use:

```py
specs = [list([{ 'secondary_y':True }]*len( arr___regions ))]
```

to specify the appropriate size spec for `len( arr___regions )`